# Cmake export compile commands for header files for Emacs

Tags: c++, emacs, cmake

What's the point of

```
cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
```

if it can only generate a compile_commands.json file for .cpp files and not for .h or .hpp files.

I'm trying to use it in tandem with irony-mode on Emacs but if I can't have code completion based on compile_commands.json for headers I think that .clang_complete is a much better option. There are a lot of C++ stuff that is header only!

Is there a way to get cmake generating compile_commands.json for headers and sources?

Thanks!

Comment: Do I understand your question correctly as a follow-up on your [`irony-mode` issue post](https://github.com/Sarcasm/irony-mode/issues/323)?

Comment: Regarding [`CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html), it "generates a `compile_commands.json` file containing the exact compiler calls for all translation units of the project". Header files itself are normally not compiled (therefore CMake does ignore them if listed as a source file, see [CMAKE_CXX_IGNORE_EXTENSIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_IGNORE_EXTENSIONS.html)), so they won't show up in the compile commands export file.

Comment: I understand exactly how and why it works the way it does it. I'm just saying that is inconvenient. Header only libraries, templates programming, etc... Anyways, I'm going back to plain Makefiles and clang_complete. Thanks for your understanding!

Comment: Right now I'm just post processing the compile_commands.json file and adding the headers myself following some simple conventions. I just wanted to hear what other people are saying. cmake is a tool, there's nothing in the way to add an option to include headers on the compile_commands.json file. Thanks!

Comment: I've been reading about ycm and I remember using it with vim before. It seems that somehow they have tooling to tackle this issue. Dumping irony-mode and getting ycm on emacs may be a nice thing to do. Will try this weekend and post here!